# How to update day and month of a date field based on another date column present in another table?

Tags: t-sql

> I have two tables namely tenant and unit.
>
> dtleaseto is the column present in tenant table. dtmovein is the
>   column present in unit table.
>
> I need to update only month and day of a date present in dtleaseto
>   with the month and day of a period which is one day prior to dtmovein.
>
> E.g. Suppose my dtlease to is 12/20/2012 and dtmovein is 01/01/2011
>   then my updated dtleaseto will be **12** / **31** /2012.
>
> *Relationship between tenant and unit is tenant.hunit = unit.hmy
>
> Thanks in advance for your help!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you might want something like this:

```
UPDATE t
  SET dtleaseto = CONVERT(date, CAST(YEAR(t.dtleaseto) AS CHAR(4)) -- Year of dtleaseto
  +SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(day,-1,u.dtmovein),112),5,4)) -- MMDD part of dtmovein-1 day
FROM tenant t
JOIN unit u on t.hunit = u.hmy
```